# Notify result from one thread to another or wait for feedback from the first thread to continue the second thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to get 2 threads running in the background to perform tasks. I have to create the threads sequentially and proceed with the program execution. But the second thread must execute it's work only when the first finishes. Also, One more clarification. I am looking to have this solution on a WPF application. There is no UI feedback needed. All I need is a status update from the first task. I agree if we do all in one thread it will be fine. But we want to have the second thread which does more things seperately even if the user leaves the screen which created this thread.

Here is the sample:

```
class Program
{

    static string outValue;
    static bool _isFinished = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart thread1 = delegate()
        {
            outValue = AnotherClass.FirstLongRunningTask();
            // I need to set the _isFinished after the long running finishes..
            // I cant wait here because I need to kick start the next thread and move on.
            // 
        };
        new Thread(thread1).Start();

        ThreadStart thread2 = delegate()
        {
            while (!_isFinished)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Inside the while loop...");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outValue))
            {
                // This should execute only if the _isFinished is true...
                AnotherClass.SecondTask(outValue);    
            }

        };
        new Thread(thread2).Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("I have to work on this while thread 1 and thread 2 and doing something ...");    
        }    
        Console.ReadLine();

    }



}


public class AnotherClass
{
    public static string FirstLongRunningTask() 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        return "From the first long running task...";
    }

    public static void SecondTask(string fromThread1) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(fromThread1);
    }
}
```

Where do I set the _isFinished?
I can't use BackgroundWorker threads. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to have sample WPF code instead of Console code if you're looking for WPF solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a thread can only start when another one finishes, you have a very simple solution: execute the entire code on the first thread.

You can use `Task.ContinueWith` to queue up more work for the same `Task`.

Comment: I agree with your comment. But is it not possible to have them in seperate threads? Also, I updated my original post to mention that the requirement is for a WPF application,

Comment: +1 to this.  You are no longer "waiting" for the thread to complete, merely defining what you want to happen when it completes--which will avoid blocking the UI.  IF you want to do something with the UI when the task completes, be sure to look into  `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: @user1549435: Yes you can have two separate threads, but from a logical point of view it does not make sense, since there is nothing happening in parallel. If B needs to wait for A to finish completely before starting, A might as well do all the work of B as well.

Comment: I am going with Tudor's suggestion and point noted. Since second is not doing anything, no need for a second thread. Fully agree..

Answer (score 2):

You should simply call `thread1.Join()`, which will block until `thread1` terminates.

However, there are a large number of better ways to do this.
You should use the TPL and the `Task` class instead.

Comment: In a WPF application, `Join` is likely a bad idea.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: I think he'd be doing that in the background thread.